# Получения текста с email письма

Tags: c#, .net, email, mailkit

есть задача получить текст с тела письма, какими способами не пробую результат тот же, получаю html.
работаю через Imap.
код:

```
    public async static Task PrintImapOne()
    {
        List<MimeMessage> messages = await ImapFetchAllMessages(FasadUser.Hostname, FasadUser.Port = 143, FasadUser.SSL, FasadUser.Login, FasadUser.Password);
        messages.Reverse();
        Console.Write(messages.First());
    }

    public static async Task<List<MimeMessage>> ImapFetchAllMessages(String hostname, Int32 port, Boolean useSsl, String username, String password)
    {
        using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
            List<MimeMessage> allMessages = null;
            await client.ConnectAsync(hostname, port, useSsl);
            await client.AuthenticateAsync(username, password);

            if(client.IsConnected)
            {
                if (client.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var inbox = client.Inbox;
                    await inbox.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);
                    allMessages = new List<MimeMessage>(inbox.Count);
                    foreach (var summary in client.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId).ToList())
                    {
                        //inbox.GetBodyPart(summary.UniqueId, summary.HtmlBody).ToString();
                        var message = await inbox.GetMessageAsync(summary.UniqueId);
                        allMessages.Add(message);
                    }
                }
            }
            return allMessages;
        }
    }
```

попробовал тоже самое с Pop3, вообще пустую строку возвращает:

```
    async static Task PrintPop3One()
    {
        List<MimeMessage> messages = await Pop3FetchAllMessages(FasadUser.Hostname, FasadUser.Port = 110, FasadUser.SSL, FasadUser.Login, FasadUser.Password);
        messages.Reverse();
        Console.Write(messages.First().GetTextBody(TextFormat.Text));
    }

    public static async Task<List<MimeMessage>> Pop3FetchAllMessages(string hostname, int port, bool useSsl, string username, string password)
    {
        using (var client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            List<MimeMessage> allMessages = null;
            await client.ConnectAsync(hostname, port, useSsl);
            await client.AuthenticateAsync(username, password);
            if (client.IsConnected)
            {
                if (client.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    var count = await client.GetMessageCountAsync();
                    allMessages = new List<MimeMessage>(count);

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    {
                        allMessages.Add(await client.GetMessageAsync(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            return allMessages;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Какая почта? Проверю потом у себя...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Outlook) я нашел решение в лоб с помощью Html Agility Pack)

Comment: Проверил. На почте имею два письма: 1. `text/plain` (обычный текст). 2. `text/html` (html письмо). Так вот суть в чем, если письмо HTML, то вы текст по сути из него через MailKit не возьмете. Вы можете сделать что то по типу `var body = message.BodyParts.OfType<TextPart>().FirstOrDefault();` и дальше обрабатывать текст (`body.Text`) как вам надо (например разбирать с помощью HAP, если `body.IsHtml == true`).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, text/plain, text/html эти параметры на сервере устанавливаются, к которому доступа нету

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, в общем Ваш метод тот же результат дает что и мой `messages.First().GetTextBody(TextFormat.Text)`, а потом пройтись по нем с помощью HAP

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, напишите ответ с коментов, я закрою вопрос)

Comment: Я не считаю это ответом. Это лишь мои догадки, которые не чем не обоснованны, я не смог найти информации почему именно в `text/html` письме не выдается текст. Если найду что то существенное, оформлю ответом, ну а для закрытия - можете оформить ответ сами, со своими наработками и конечным результатом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ok :)